# How do I fix a Python Try/Except statement that is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-except

I am trying to incorporate some error handling within my Python program so that whenever my image conversion code block throws an error that will won't stop the program but will keep on going but every time I get an error it stops the program.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is my code:

```
if file.lower().endswith('.tif'): # <-- If file is a TIFF file and there are no errors yet
    try:
        imwrite(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg', imread(filepath)[:,:,:3].copy()) # <-- using the imagecodecs library function of imread, make a copy in memory of the TIFF File.
        # The :3 on the end of the numpy array is stripping the alpha channel from the TIFF file if it has one so it can be easily converted to a JPEG file.
        # Once the copy is made the imwrite function is creating a JPEG file from the TIFF file.
        # The [:-4] is stripping off the .tif extension from the file and the + '.jpg' is adding the .jpg extension to the newly created JPEG file.
        img = Image.open(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg') # <-- Using the Image.open function from the Pillow library, we are getting the newly created JPEG file and opening it.
        img = img.convert('RGB') # <-- Using the convert function we are making sure to convert the JPEG file to RGB color mode.
        imageResize = img.resize((2500, 2500)) # <-- Using the resize function we are resizing the JPEG to 2500 x 2500
        imageResize.save(filepath[:-4] + '.jpg') # <-- Using the save function, we are saving the newly sized JPEG file over the original JPEG file initially created.
    except ValueError:
        print('There was an error with the Image')
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You probably do not handle the correct error. Stacktrace please. [edit] your post.

Comment: I get the Exception has occurred: ValueError message

Comment: I also tried the except: continue and it still stops the program with the error

Comment: Why does the first line use `file` while the rest uses `filepath`?

Comment: @MarkRansom file and filepath are two variables used earlier in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **except ValueError** you should do **except Exception** since the possible problem is that the thrown error is **NOT** a value error, so now if any error happens it will enter the Except part

```
   try:
       do something
   except Exception:
       do something else
```

Comment: I tried that and it still is throwing the error

Comment: Then 100% the error isn't in this line of code, it could be in the If statement or any other block of code